# Вывод двух таблиц из базы

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

нужно вывести посты на одной странице с учетом, что один пост состоит из двух таблиц, вот картинка для понимания того, что мне нужно вывести. Nо, что выделено красным содержится в одной таблице, что синим в другой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну и соответственно как выглядят две таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А здесь уже конкретно мой пример, для начала я объединяю две таблицы

```
$res_post = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, date, author, content, name_image FROM post_en LEFT JOIN image_post ON post_id=id_post_en");
```

Получается в итоге так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как дальше уже вывести на страницу эти данные я не понимаю (возможно я изначально делаю все не так как надо). Но вообще предполагаю. что все это нужно выводить через массив, но не знаю как.

Comment: Правильней всего сделать через 2 запроса: 1ый запрос - выбрать все новости которые нам нужны для страницы. 2ой запрос - выбрать их картинки (мы уже знаем какие новости нам нужны и по айдшкам запрашиваем картинки). В итоге получается 2 массива: новости и картинки. Ну а там уже все должны понять как добить.

Comment: Я просто не знаю как эти два запроса вывести в итоге в один пост

Comment: foreach ($MAS_WITH_POST as $POST) { echo $POST['text']; foreach ($MAS_WITH_IMAGE as $IMAGE) { if($POST['Id_post'] == $IMAGE['Id_post_table1']) { echo $IMAGE['name_img']; } } }

Comment: Это костыльный пример, но делает то что нужно, а в идеале нужно преобразовать массив с картинками так, чтобы ключ был равен id_post, а значение - это массив с картинками этого поста.

Comment: Я просто очень плохо разбираюсь во всем этом, хотел так попробовать, но так навероне не правильно, потому как не получается $res_post = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, date, author, content FROM post_en");    while($row_sezon = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_post)){$row_sezon['post_id'] = $rrrr; $res_img = mysql_query("SELECT name_img FROM image_post WHERE id_post_en={'$rrrr'}");
  while($row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_img)){     }   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тот запрос, что на скрине можно обработать следующим образом.

```
$posts = $imgs = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    $imgs[$row['post_id']][] = $row['name_image'];
    $row['images'] = $imgs[$row['post_id']];
    $posts[$row['post_id']] = $row;
}
// на странице разобрать массив $posts
```

Есть еще вариант вывести все посты на страницу без картинок, а после отрисовки страницы с помощью js собрать айдишники постов, отправить на сервер и получить картинки, сформировать списки картинок для каждого поста, вернуть на клиент и добавить эти картинки соответствующему посту.

Вариант с запросом на получение картинок для каждого поста в цикле не самый хороший, но если на странице всего 10 постов, то +10 запросов в БД не сильно страшно. Особенно, если делать это в методах класса, чтобы память очищалась.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но если честно не понял как это реализовать, но по крайней мере пост ниже подошел, правда со стилями проблема небольшая

Comment: В $rows строки, которые пришли из БД. Циклом готовим массив $posts, который надо разобрать на странице для отображения постов. В $posts[N]['images'] будет массив с картинками, который надо дополнительно прогнать форичем.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, единственное когда выводит массив, получается дублируются вещи, может подскажете, как можно избежать дублирования         [2] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [date] => 2018-05-15
            [1] => 2018-05-15
            [author] => dfgdfgdfg
            [2] => dfgdfgdfg

Comment: Вероятно, при получении данных из БД используется mysql_fetch_array(), при использовании mysql_fetch_assoc() будет формироваться ассоциативный массив без цифровых ключей.

Answer (score 1):

Тож немного костыльно, но можно просто перебирая массив не выводить ненужное когда пост "тот же", а выводить только картинки:

```
   foreach ($rows as $row ){
      if( $row['post_id'] != $last_id ){
          echo $row['date'];
          echo $row['title'];
          echo $row['text'];
          $last_id = $row['post_id'];
      }
      echo '<img src="'.$row['pic'].'">;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо, думаю что на первое время данный код подойдет, единственное стили нарушаются, нельзя его как нибудь подстроить так чтоб стили не нарушались?